# How to extract cell values from a raster file with Idrisi Taiga?

Tags: raster, point, export, table, terrset

I need to convert raster cells into points. I use Idrisi and I need to generate a table containing xy (coordinates) and z (cell value).

Answer (score 1):

If it is a single band raster, you can use gdal_translate:

```
kyle@kyle-workstation:Desktop$ gdal_translate -b 1 -of XYZ -co ADD_HEADER_LINE=YES kyle.png test.xyz
Input file size is 992, 744
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
kyle@kyle-workstation:Desktop$ head test.xyz 
X Y Z
0.5 0.5 208
1.5 0.5 211
2.5 0.5 210
3.5 0.5 211
4.5 0.5 208
5.5 0.5 211
6.5 0.5 209
7.5 0.5 210
8.5 0.5 211
```

-b is band selection, the -co adds the header line.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in IDRISI 17.0
export--->general convertions tools--->XYZ IDRISI

Comment: Thanks for the commet but xyz idris export tool is for vector data only (at least in Taiga). I need to get the cell values of an image in tabular for.

Comment: First convert your raster to vector and then do as I said before (export)..you will get x,y,z file